# ¿Cómo eliminar de la multilista el o los meses donde el promedio del dolar es menor a 25 pesos?

Tags: c

Desarrollar un programa en C que permita cargar los datos en una multilista de la siguiente manera:

En la lista principal se ingresan diferentes años, ordenados de menor a mayor y por cada año, el mes y cotización promedio del dólar durante ese mes. La carga termina con 0 en ambos casos. Mostrar la mulitilista.

Ingresar el año actual, el mes actual y la cotización promedio del dólar e insertarlo en la multilista. Borrar de la multilista él o los meses donde le promedio de la cotización del dólar fue menor a 25 pesos.

Mostrar la multilista.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct lista1 {
    int anio;
    struct lista2 *d;
    struct lista1*sig;
}nodo1;

typedef struct lista2 {
    int mes;
    int cotizacionDolar;
    struct lista2 *sig2;
}nodo2;

void mostrarlista(nodo1 *);
void cargaranios(nodo1 *);

int main()
{
    nodo1 *p=NULL;
    p=(nodo1*)malloc(sizeof(nodo1));
    cargaranios(p);
    mostrarlista(p);

    //getch();
}


void cargaranios(nodo1 *p)
{
    printf("\nIngrese el anio (0 para finalizar): ");
    scanf("%d", &p->anio);
    if (p->anio==0)
    {
        p->sig=NULL;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        p->d=(nodo2*)malloc(sizeof(nodo2));
        cargardatos(p->d);
        p->sig=(nodo1*)malloc(sizeof(nodo1));
        cargaranios(p->sig);
    }
}

void cargardatos(nodo2 *r)
{
    printf("\nIngrese el mes (0 para finalizar): ");
    scanf("%d",&r->mes);
    if (r->mes==0)
    {
        r->sig2=NULL;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nIngrese la cotización promedio del dolar: ");
        scanf("%d", &r->cotizacionDolar);
        r->sig2=(nodo2*)malloc(sizeof(nodo2));
        cargardatos(r->sig2);
    }
}

void mostrarlista(nodo1 *p)
{
    if (p->sig!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nAnio: %d \n", p->anio);
        mostrardatos(p->d);
        mostrarlista(p->sig);
    }
}

void mostrardatos(nodo2 *r)
{
    if (r->sig2!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Mes: %d\n", r->mes);
        printf("Promedio dolar: %d\n", r->cotizacionDolar);
        mostrardatos(r->sig2);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: En principio, no logro mostrar la multilista, y luego no entiendo como borrar los meses donde la cotización del dolar fue menor a 25

Comment: ¿Qué significa "no mostrar la multilista"? ¿Qué errores tienes? ¿Cuáles son tus datos de entrada? ¿Qué datos esperas como salida? ¿Qué no entiendes del borrado de datos?

Comment: Cuando ejecuto el código, ingreso año, mes y promedio del dolar. y se sale del programa, no encuentro el error.

Comment: Y el borrado de datos, no consigo lograrlo tampoco

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a stackoverflow! Te invito a leer esto: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Te recomiendo editar la pregunta y que agregues información detallada del problema. La pregunta debe ser más especifica. No incluyas en una pregunta otras preguntas, porque la respuesta se vuelve extensa.

Comment: El ejercicio parece interesante. El problema es que debes definir de forma detallada cual es la duda con ese código, de lo contrario, nadie responderá, porque no saben **cual es el problema** o la inquietud que tienes. También ten en cuenta que si no editas la pregunta, terminará cerrada.

Comment: El código ni compila. Señala en todo caso dónde y en qué falla.

Comment: Hola @MrDave1999, cómo estás? soy nuevo y de a poco me estoy adaptando a la plataforma, gracias por el consejo. Ya modifique la pregunta.

Comment: Hola @user3733164, cómo estás? ya logré corregir el código y compila bien, solo me faltaría lo que indique en la nueva pregunta, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He implementado una función para borrar los elementos de la sublista (lista de meses que penden de cada año) que no cumplan la condición:

```
void borrarCotizacion(lista_anios *p, int cotizacion)
{
    while (p->sig != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nAnio: %d \n", p->anio);
        lista_meses* nodoborrar = p->d;
        lista_meses* nodoanterior = NULL;
        while(nodoborrar->sig2!=NULL)
        {
            if (nodoborrar->cotizacionDolar<MINIMA_COTIZACION)
            {
                printf("La cotizacion %d del mes %d del anno %d es menor que %d y se borrara\n",nodoborrar->cotizacionDolar,nodoborrar->mes,p->anio,MINIMA_COTIZACION);
                if (!nodoanterior)//primer elemento
                {
                    p->d=p->d->sig2;//hago que el primer elemento de la sublista apunte al siguiente elemento
                }
                else
                {
                    nodoanterior->sig2 = nodoborrar->sig2;
                }
                free(nodoborrar);
            }
            nodoanterior = nodoborrar;
            nodoborrar = nodoborrar->sig2;
        }
        p=p->sig;
    }
}
```

Para ello guardamos un puntero a la lista original y entramos en la función con ese puntero y con el valor de comparación.
Cada vez que recorremos la lista de meses, a su vez deberemos crear dos punteros más:

```
lista_meses* nodoborrar = p->d;
lista_meses* nodoanterior = NULL;
```

Uno apunta al inicio de la lista de meses y el otro a NULL.
Cuando nos encontremos con un valor que satisface las condiciones del borrado, lo primero es saber si es el primer elemento de esa lista. Si esto es así, "puenteamos" el primer elemento al siguiente:

```
if (!nodoanterior)//primer elemento
{
    p->d=p->d->sig2;//hago que el primer elemento de la sublista apunte al siguiente elemento
}
```

Y si es otro elemento cualquiera, hacemos que el anterior apunte al siguiente, para desligar el elemento a borrar

```
else
{
    nodoanterior->sig2 = nodoborrar->sig2;
}
```

Una vez liberado el nodo, en cualquiera de las dos *versiones*, sólo queda liberar la memoria ocupada por dicho nodo:

```
free(nodoborrar);
```

Como ves, he cambiado algunos nombres para que sean más descriptivos. Siempre es bueno que los nombres de las variables o tipos de datos sean lo más descriptivos posibles.

Aquí va el código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct lista1
{
    int anio;
    struct lista2 *d;
    struct lista1*sig;
} lista_anios;

typedef struct lista2
{
    int mes;
    int cotizacionDolar;
    struct lista2 *sig2;
} lista_meses;

#define MINIMA_COTIZACION 25

void mostrarlista(lista_anios *);
void cargaranios(lista_anios *);
void cargardatos(lista_meses *r);
void mostrardatos(lista_meses *r);
void borrarCotizacion(lista_anios* p, int cotizacion);

int main()
{
    lista_anios *p=NULL;
    p=(lista_anios*)malloc(sizeof(lista_anios));
    cargaranios(p);
    mostrarlista(p);
    lista_anios *la=p;//uso un puntero aparte para mantener p en el origen de la lista
    borrarCotizacion(la,MINIMA_COTIZACION);
    mostrarlista(p);

    //getch();
}


void cargaranios(lista_anios *p)
{
    printf("\nIngrese el anio (0 para finalizar): ");
    scanf("%d", &p->anio);
    if (p->anio==0)
    {
        p->sig=NULL;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        p->d=(lista_meses*)malloc(sizeof(lista_meses));
        cargardatos(p->d);
        p->sig=(lista_anios*)malloc(sizeof(lista_anios));
        cargaranios(p->sig);
    }
}

void cargardatos(lista_meses *r)
{
    printf("\nIngrese el mes (0 para finalizar): ");
    scanf("%d",&r->mes);
    if (r->mes==0)
    {
        r->sig2=NULL;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nIngrese la cotización promedio del dolar: ");
        scanf("%d", &r->cotizacionDolar);
        r->sig2=(lista_meses*)malloc(sizeof(lista_meses));
        cargardatos(r->sig2);
    }
}

void mostrarlista(lista_anios *p)
{
    if (p->sig!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nAnio: %d \n", p->anio);
        mostrardatos(p->d);
        mostrarlista(p->sig);
    }
}

void mostrardatos(lista_meses *r)
{
    if (r->sig2!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Mes: %d\n", r->mes);
        printf("Promedio dolar: %d\n", r->cotizacionDolar);
        mostrardatos(r->sig2);
    }
}

void borrarCotizacion(lista_anios *p, int cotizacion)
{
    while (p->sig != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nAnio: %d \n", p->anio);
        lista_meses* nodoborrar = p->d;
        lista_meses* nodoanterior = NULL;
        while(nodoborrar->sig2!=NULL)
        {
            if (nodoborrar->cotizacionDolar<MINIMA_COTIZACION)
            {
                printf("La cotizacion %d del mes %d del anno %d es menor que %d y se borrara\n",nodoborrar->cotizacionDolar,nodoborrar->mes,p->anio,MINIMA_COTIZACION);
                if (!nodoanterior)//primer elemento
                {
                    p->d=p->d->sig2;//hago que el primer elemento de la sublista apunte al siguiente elemento
                }
                else
                {
                    nodoanterior->sig2 = nodoborrar->sig2;
                }
                free(nodoborrar);
            }
            nodoanterior = nodoborrar;
            nodoborrar = nodoborrar->sig2;
        }
        p=p->sig;
    }
}
```

Un ejemplo funcionando:
https://onlinegdb.com/Sy19csf3U

Comment: Gracias. Ahora estoy tratando de que me compile el código.

Comment: No entiendo. No te compila el código? Si es así, qué errores te da?

Comment: No me compila. a vos si?

Comment: Claro. El código está correcto y funciona. ¿Qué problemas te da?

Comment: Me da los siguientes errores.

_main.c:24:54: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘=’ token
 void borrarCotizacion(lista_anios* p, int cotizacion = MINIMA_COTIZACION);

main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:33:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘borrarCotizacion’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     borrarCotizacion(la);

main.c: At top level:
main.c:96:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘borrarCotizacion’void borrarCotizacion(lista_anios *p, int cotizacion)

main.c:33:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘borrarCotizacion’ was here borrarCotizacion(la);_

Comment: Te dejo el código aquí, por si lo quieres comprobar: https://onlinegdb.com/HJJHfifhL

Comment: Ahí entendí lo que pasa, el ejercicio como dice la consigna es en C y no en C++, es decir que yo lo ejecuto en C y vos lo estas ejecutando en C++.

Comment: Ahhh...lo siento. El caso es que C no admite valores por defecto en la función, así que no se puede hacer esto void borrarCotizacion(lista_anios* p, int cotizacion=VALOR); He quitado esta parte (del signo = en adelante). También he cambiado el valor de MINIMA_COTIZACION que ahora es un #define. Con esto debería de funcionar....espero! He actualizado el enlace: https://onlinegdb.com/Sy19csf3U

Comment: Muchas gracias. Funciona perfecto!!!